# Разделение разрядов c помощью аргумента fmt в bar_label()

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, seaborn

Я использую bar_label(), чтобы добавить значения к столбцам столбчатой диаграммы sns.barplot.

```
chart = sns.barplot(data=total_sales, palette="rocket", x="year", y="value_1000", hue='market')
chart.bar_label(chart.containers[0], fmt='%d', padding=3, fontsize=10)
```

Никак не могу понять, как записать fmt таким образом, чтобы разряды разделялись запятой.

Глобально установлено:
`pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:,.2f}'.format)`

Но работает только для таблицы. Пробовал записать `fmt='%:,.2f'` не помогает. Другие вариации с запятой, вроде `fmt='%,d'` - приводят к ошибке.

Comment: А это какая версия `seaborn`? В моей нет `bar_label`.

Comment: matplotlib - 3.5.1, seaborn - 0.11.2

Comment: pd.set_option - это не глобально. это для pandas. и, если я не ошибаюсь, bar_label() - это matplotlib, а не seaborn

Answer (score 0):

Вы не там изменяете форматирование.

Я предполагаю, что вам понадобится использовать локаль.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = [11.5,12.5,5.5]

ax.bar(x = [1,2,3], height=data)
container = ax.containers[0]
ax.bar_label(container, labels=[f"{locale.format_string('%.3f', x)}" for x in container.datavalues])
```

получите такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам за идею! Совсем забыл про существование аргумента labels. В итоге без использовании локали заработало вот так:   

```chart = sns.barplot(data=total_sales, x=x, y=y,  palette="rocket")  

chart.bar_label(chart.containers[0], labels=[f'{x:,.2f}' for x in y], padding=3, fontsize=10)```